# Is there a way to prevent mail clients from caching an email address?

Tags: email, caching, header, smtp

We have an application that allows users exchange messages, and delivers the message through email. But we don't reveal sender's email, instead; every time a message is sent out a new email address gets generated for the "From" field. Something similar to the way Facebook or LinkedIn send out messages.
Everything works fine, except the recipient's email client caches all these email addresses. 
For instance, if Jack sends two messages to Jill, the sender's addresses can be: a123@FakeEmail.com and a456@FakeEmail.com, so next time Jill composes a new message and starts typing Jack's name, the email client suggests two addresses for Jack.

So my question is, how we can prevent email caching on client's machine? Is there something similar to HTTP header Pragma: no-cache for SMTP?

Thanks
Nivresh

Comment: Some user feedback on your approach to email: I had one cmapny I dealt with that adopted a similar approach. I couldn't reply easily to their emails for the reason you have identified, nor could I automatically filter, prioritise, download pictures or anything else. Their emails became a pain because they all had to be dealt with individually. Finally, I simply unsusbcribed, and they lost a customer. User experience is everything - be careful.

Comment: Mike, thanks for the heads up. You are absolutely right, our goal is to provide a user-friendly environment for our clients, and we are very careful about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here is what I ended up doing. To prevent Outlook and other mail clients from suggesting several dummy email addresses generated for the same contact name, I add a special character to the beginning of the sender's name. This can be a space or if you use Unicode, you can add a zero-width space (\u200B) to the beginning of the name. 
So in my example, the email is sent from "\u200BJack" which will be shown as "Jack". The dummy email address will be saved in mail client under the name of "\u200BJack" and when the recipient later on tries to send an email to Jack, email client won't suggest this address.
Hope this helps someone.